# Issues after rooting my Galaxy S2 by running fk23, the Jellybean ROM

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, rooting

Recently rooted to fk23 and have the following problems:

- Having problems with lock screen.
- Will not let me modify/change anything.
- Time is displayed in `military`
  or `24 hrs format`.
- Unchecked clock in settings and nothing changes.
- Can't change background picture.
- There are **no** plus signs when on lock screen to change anything.

> Tried to change settings to secure with pattern, now I have **two** lock screens to go through. 
>   
>   Anyone have any idea on how to solve these?

Comment: On the lockscreen there are usually no "plus signs". With the standard lockscreens, modifications you can make are quite minimal -- unless you have a special app installed (e.g. [WidgetLocker Lockscreen](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teslacoilsw.widgetlocker)). Same for the "double lockscreen": That's also normal. Again, some special apps might exist to change that.

Comment: @Izzy I think the "plus sign" is the button to add a widget to the lock screen, which looks like a rectangle with rounded corners and a + inside. It's part of the stock lock screen on 4.1 and later.

Comment: @DanHulme Strange -- I never saw that on my lock screens, not even on 4.1.1. But maybe that's because of "stock != stock"...

Answer (score 0):

I think it is due to u have use wrong Rooting file. did you tried other Rooting file as well? 
what i tried is I9100ZSLSJ Android 4.1.2 Jelly Bean Galaxy S2 I9100
if you want to download it. here is [the link](http://androidmuffins.com/tag/galaxy-s2-i9100-root/)

Comment: Sorry,  i had someone root the phone for me,  so im not sure how he did it.  Could he have given me internatiobal version?  Don't know why clock  on lock screen is in military?